# Not able to get windowhandle of already open IE window

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to automate citrix login process at my organization.
I am using ChromeDriver ( selenium ) to automate few steps which is successful till now.
But it downloads .ica file which I need to double click and which opens fresh IE browser instance.
I am not able to get handle of this instance. I want to enter username and password programmatically in this newly opened IE window.

My code is as below.

```
 // Code which downloads ica file
 var idCitrix = chromedriver.FindElementById("IdOfDOMElement");
 idCitrix.Click();
 // Below code will ALWAYS OPEN IE FRESH BROWSER INSTANCE (IE 11)
 Process.Start("LOCATION OF .ICA FILR FROM DOWNLOADS FOLDER");
 //How to get handle of this newly opened IE window ??
```